# Asp.Net Core SignalR reconnectivity issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using .Net 5 SignalR, its working and invoking hub method untill I am connected  to internet,
Once I got disconnected the websocket connection is closed after timeout of 15 seconds and then I am unable to restart the connection again as show in below screen shot.
We have two types of connections states, hubConnection and httpConnection, hubConnection state is connected but httpconnection states is disconnected.

[image]

Now I am unable to start the httpConnection and I am getting below error.

[image]

Note: I do not want to use withAutomaticReconnect while creating HubConnection using HubConnectionBuilder, also if I increase timeout then this situation will occur after that timeout.
Need help.

[image]

Code sample:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub?UserId=10370")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Error)
        .build();
function startConnection() {
        connection.start().then(function () {
            console.log("signalR is connected!")
            document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
            connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then(connectionid => {
                document.getElementById("connectionId").textContent = connectionid;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        }).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });

    }
    function reconnect() {
        setTimeout(startConnection, 2000);
    }

    startConnection();
    connection.onclose(function (data) {
        console.log("Hub connection onclosed | reconnect: " + data);
        reconnect();
    });
```

Comment: Can you share your sample code?

Comment: Done, also updated description.